# How do I copy files from GitHub without cloning?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

There exists a public repository on GitHub.  I have a terminal open to an empty directory on my own machine, and I would like to fill that directory with the set of files represented by a particular branch of this repository.

All I want is the fileset that constitutes the latest commit to the given branch.  I don't need any history or revision metadata.  It would be a waste of bandwidth, computation, and storage to `git clone` the repo or otherwise create a Git repository locally.  It seems intuitive that there would be a command for me to download the set of files:

```
$ git {something} https://github.com/OrgName/RepoName.git branchname
```

to copy these files into the current directory.  I've been looking for hours, and I can find nothing.  There's too much "`git clone`" noise to every web search I've tried.

Is this possible, and how?  If it is possible, can it be done without authenticating to GitHub?

Comment: Does the repo have any "releases"? Often you can download a zip file with the code for a specific release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple ways you can go about getting a single revision.

First, on GitHub, there are API endpoints for downloading [a tarball](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive-tar) or [a zip file](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#download-a-repository-archive-zip) of a particular revision.  They can be downloaded using curl, and require authentication only if the repository is private.

If the repository has release assets that contain a specific tarball or other archive that you want to download, you can first [look up the release](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-release-asset) and then [download the asset](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#get-a-release-asset) you want.  This is helpful if releases contain generated files or other things that won't be in the autogenerated tarballs.

You can also choose to do a shallow clone.  That is, you can pass the `--depth 1` option to `git clone` to download the data for only one revision, and you can specify a branch with the `-b BRANCH` option.  That will end up with a `.git` directory, which you can delete if you want, or you can use `git archive HEAD` to generate an archive from that.

Comment: The tarball download seems to be the best answer, and I can confirm that it works.  For other users with the same problem, I will note that the tarball extracts the fileset into an ad-hoc folder named `{repo}-{branch}/`, so you'll have to move the repo files from that folder into the current folder manually.  Still, this is likely as close as it's possible to get.

Answer (score 4):

I think there is only the following solution:

```
   git clone -b branchname --depth 1 --single-branch https://github.com/OrgName/RepoName.git \
&& rm -rf RepoName/.git/
```

It clones a single branch (`-b branchname --single-branch`), taking only the last commi (`--depth = 1`), the it removes then `.git` folder.

Answer (score 2):

You can just download it.

```
wget https://github.com/OrgName/RepoName/archive/refs/heads/branchname.zip
```